# Selectonemenu always saves the same value in the database

Tags: spring, primefaces

Here is my controller!
Controller:

public void updateUserdocOrgScnd(RowEditEvent event) {
        try {
            LOG.info("\n\n\nINSIDE \n CLASS == DocumentController \n METHOD == updateUserdocOrgScnd(); ");

```
        Dmsuserdocorgscndry dmsuserdocorgscndry = (Dmsuserdocorgscndry) event.getObject();
        apexManagerService = ServiceManagerFactory.getServiceManager(getServletContext());
        final DocumentService documentService = apexManagerService.getDocumentService();
        DocumentBean documentBean = (DocumentBean) getControllerObject(ApexManagedBean.DOCUMENTBEAN.getName(),
                DocumentBean.class);

        if (dmsuserdocorgscndry.getUdostatus().equals("true")) {
            dmsuserdocorgscndry.setUdostatus("A");
        } else {
            dmsuserdocorgscndry.setUdostatus("I");
        }

        if (dmsuserdocorgscndry != null) {
            if (dmsuserdocorgscndry.getDoclevel().equals("C")) {
                dmsuserdocorgscndry.setDoclevel("C");
            } else if (dmsuserdocorgscndry.getDoclevel().equals("A")) {
                dmsuserdocorgscndry.setDoclevel("A");
            } else if (dmsuserdocorgscndry.getDoclevel().equals("P")) {
                dmsuserdocorgscndry.setDoclevel("P");
            } else if (dmsuserdocorgscndry.getDoclevel().equals("S")) {
                dmsuserdocorgscndry.setDoclevel("S");
            } else if (dmsuserdocorgscndry.getDoclevel().equals("U")) {
                dmsuserdocorgscndry.setDoclevel("U");
            } else if (dmsuserdocorgscndry.getDoclevel().equals("G")) {
                dmsuserdocorgscndry.setDoclevel("G");
            }

            documentBean.setDoclevelscndry(dmsuserdocorgscndry.getDoclevel());
        }

        dmsuserdocorgscndry = documentService.updateOrgScnd(dmsuserdocorgscndry);

        if (dmsuserdocorgscndry != null) {
            addMessageToFacesContext(SUCCESS_UPDATE);

        } else {
            addMessageToFacesContext(ERROR_UPDATE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        addMessageToFacesContext(ERROR_UPDATE);
    }
    LOG.info("EXITING THIS METHOD \n\n\n");
}
```

Comment: `Saves the same value in the database` doesn't properly scope the issue. I mean, how do you know if it's a JSF related problem or a business layer problem if you just look at the value saved in the database? Do some debugging and see if the selectonemenu is giving you the wrong value in the managed bean, then you might focus the problem.

Comment: And in general improve your question (formatting, version info, [mcve])